# The component is declared by more than one NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript

So i created a component **ExampleComponent** and declared it in a module that **isnt** listed in app.module.
Next i want to declare the component **ExampleComponent** in a module that **is** listed in app.module. How do i do this? If i simply declare it, than i get the following error: the component **ExampleComponent** is declared by more than one NgModule.

abc.module.ts

```
import { ExampleComponent } from '../Example/Example.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ExampleComponent
  ]
})
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NewModule } from '../new/new.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NewModule
  declarations: [
    
  ]
})
```

new.module

```
import { ExampleComponent } from '../Example/Example.component';
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ExampleComponent
      ]
    })
```

Comment: If that is inside an other module then put it in `imports:[...here...]`

Answer (score 103):

If you use your component in multiple modules, it means that this component is shared.
You need to create an exclusive module (`ExampleModule`) for your `ExampleComponent`, and then import that module wherever you want to use `ExampleComponent`.

So create ExampleModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleComponent} from '../Example/Example.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ExampleComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    ExampleComponent,
  ]
})
export class ExampleModule { }
```

And then import it where you want to use `ExampleComponent` (into `abc module` and `app module`) like that:

```
import { ExampleModule } from '../example.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ExampleModule 
  ]
  ...
})
```

By defining separate module for your shared component, you provide some encapsulation layer in which you can describe and provide all the needed dependencies for your component to work, so, in the future, all the consumers just need to import the module itself without need to know any information about all these dependencies.

Comment: For my case, in `ExampleNodule` I still need to import Common Module in addition to this for my component to work: `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` `imports: [CommonModule, ExampleModule]`

Comment: Or as I like to say, just bury it in a module so it doesn't know or care.

Answer (score 13):

**This error occurs in case if the component is being imported in the ***app.module.ts*** file instead of the module file.**

case study:

I have the folder structure as below:

```
app 
   src 
     component 
        general.component.ts 
        general.component.html 
        general.component.scss 
        general.component.spect 
        general.module.ts
        general.model.ts 
        general.services.ts
app.module.ts
app.routing.ts
```

The error ***"The component is declared by more than one NgModule"*** will be occuring when

in app.module.ts file if you have imported as below;

**`import { GeneralComponent } from './component/general/graph.component';`**

```
@NgModule({
          declarations: [
           GeneralComponent
          ],
    })
```

***Changes to overcome the issue***

1. export the general.component inside general.module.ts as shown below:

**general.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
    import { GeneralComponent } from './general.component'    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [GeneralModule.rootComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule],
      exports: [GeneralModule.rootComponent],
      entryComponents: [GeneralModule.rootComponent],
    })
    export class GeneralModule {
      static rootComponent = GeneralComponent
    }
```

2. In app.module.ts import general.module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { GeneralModule } from './component/graph-general/graph-general.module';
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
      ],
      imports: [  
         GeneralModule ,
    ]
    }) 
    export class AppModule { 
}
```

NOTE: Always only components should be in declaration and all modules should be in imports.

Comment: The premise of this response ("This error occurs in case if the component is being imported in the app.module.ts file instead of the module file.") isn't exactly true, as this can also happen when the component is declared in two modules, even if it's not imported in app.module.ts.

Comment: Yes but what if all of the other components that are declared in the general module also need it? You have to include it then.

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.module.ts` file you should only have imported the `Module` that wraps your `Component` since it's your highest import level.

In my case I bring you the following example:

`layout.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ToolbarComponent // HERE.
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ToolbarComponent // HERE.
  ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule, // HERE.
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And that's all!
With this setup I have full access to the `Component` `Selector` `<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>` in my `app.component.html` just importing `LayoutModule`.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a component via **Angular Cli**, this component should be automatically added to the app.module.ts file of your application, both in the import and decoration sections.
So, if **Angular Cli** does not perform these operations after creating the component and you add it yourself, a repetition occurs in the background and you will encounter such errors.
Solution: This error may be related to the version of Angular CLI and your **internet connection**, that is, Angular CLI cannot perform some operations for some reasons.